# why is OnPointerExit not called if the object the pointer is over is deactivated

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a UI element with OnPointerEnter and OnPointerExit which work as I would expect while moving the mouse but if I have the mouse over the UI element and I press a different key to remove the UI element without moving the mouse away the OnPointerExit code is not called

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class UIInteractions : MonoBehaviour,IPointerEnterHandler,IPointerExitHandler
{
    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("Pointer has entered " + gameObject.name);
        PlayerControls.instance.UItarget = this;
    }

    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("Pointer has exited " + gameObject.name);
        PlayerControls.instance.UItarget = null;
    }
```

this is the code from another scrip which toggles the object with the UIInteractions script

```
 if (Input.GetKeyDown("j"))
        {
            Journal.instance.ToggleJournal();
            journalOpen = Journal.instance.journalPrefab.activeSelf;
            if(journalOpen == false)
            {
                UItarget = null;
            }
        }
```

the ToggleJournal method is

```
public void ToggleJournal()
    {
        journalPrefab.SetActive(!journalPrefab.activeSelf);
    }
```

if anybody has any insight as to why the OnPointerExit is not called when the ToggleJournal method is used or any potential workaround that would be much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2):

FIX Example:

If you have a script that implements from OnPointerEnter and OnPointerExit, attached to an object in the scene.

what ever logic you have in the OnPointerExit, you can either execute that code or method in the
OnDestroy()
OnDisable()
aswell as in the OnpointerExit

e.g. i had this problem with a tooltip being showed. and i had the hide tooltip method being executed in the OnPointerExit.
when the object was deleted the tooltip stayed up, which looked stupid.

so i also called that hide method in destory and disable, so it will always get called

SO IN YOUR CASE I WOULD

create a method called

```
private void UpdatePlayerControls()
{
    Debug.Log("Pointer has exited " + gameObject.name);
    PlayerControls.instance.UItarget = null;
}
```

and the execute this method from OnPointerExit(), OnDisable() and OnDestroy()

Hope it helped
Ricky

Comment: OnDestroy worked like a charm. Most likely spared me a few hundred lines of my own potential crap. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A few ways to do it.

The simplest would be to add a UI element on the background that simply sets the UITarget to null on OnPointerEnter, instead of using OnPointerExit.

Another way is to also check that the current instance is the target on OnDisable, and if so, set it to null.